# sql-Generate random integers of 64 bits

Tags: sql, random, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to generate 64 bit random ints using Spark SQL to insert as surragate key for already existing table

I tried `FLOOR(RAND()*( POW(2,64) -1)`the numbers I get look like 1.2345 or 9.678E
How I generate the numbers correctely?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: would generating the binary form help?

Comment: Why are you generating random numbers with Spark SQL instead of Scala/Python/Java or whatever language you're using Spark with?

Comment: Becouse I need it as surragate key for my SQL table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`floor` return `double` not `bigint` / `long`. You should cast to `long` / `LongType` to get integers. For example uf you want only positive values then something like this should do the trick:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1L, "foo"), (2L, "bar"), (3L, "baz"))).toDF("x", "y")

df.select(((rand * Long.MaxValue)).cast("long").alias("rnd")).show

// +-------------------+
// |                rnd|
// +-------------------+
// |2231557941154186240|
// | 494304530857112576|
// |7931286845854403584|
// +-------------------+
```

If all you want is to generate surrogate key it is better to use `monotonicallyIncreasingId`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonicallyIncreasingId

df.select(monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```